# Vimperator seems to search with Google by default – how to change that

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, vimperator, iceweasel

On a Debian system I use

- Mozilla Iceweasel 10.0.11, with
- Vimperator 3.5.

I want to change the search engine which vimperator (not iceweasel) seems to use by default.

If I type things like `:open thing_I_wanna_lookup` vimperator opens Google to search. I already changed the `keyword.URL`-entry in the about:config and also the `browser.search.defaultenginename`-entry. I couldn't find any other suspicious entries containing "google" somewhere. There are entries containing "google" – but they don't *seem* to have anything to do with searches. I didn't want to blindly change them.

If I use the regular adress bar to type in stuff and then press enter, it really uses my preferred search engine and not Google.

Comment: So, is it or is it not using your preferred search engine? Your last line is a bit confusing.

Comment: It *does* when I type `search_item` in the regular adress bar which is part of the gui. I mean the one on top that you always have, even without vimperator installed. It *does not* when I type `:open search_item` in the command prompt for vimperator at the bottom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:** You need to use this command
`:set defsearch=[search engine name]`
and not the one I suggested earlier.

---

Enter `:dialog searchengines` and a a Dialogue box will pop up with a list of available search engines.

Select the one you want and press Okay.

Comment: This doesn't work (yet). But by removing Google from the list of search engines shown in the dialog, at least it doesn't search with Google by default. +1 for that.

Comment: **:set defsearch=yahoo** I can't believe I made such a mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I didn't find this in the vimperator help pages!

Comment: :set defsearch=google works for the FireFox 34 update, which set the default to Yahoo.